# Three factor variables to one factor variable

Tags: r

I have data with three factor variables: MI, Ang, Stroke. And I want to make them one factor variable, CVD (YES, NO).

It should be, basically:

```
IF MI=="YES" or Ang=="YES" or Stroke=="YES" then CVD=="YES" else CVD=="NO"
```

But that doesn't work obviously. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

@BWilliams got it

Solution

```
CVD <- ifelse (MI=="YES" | Ang=="YES" | Stroke=="YES", "YES","NO")
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with expected output

Comment: Use ifelse  `CVD = ifelse(MI=="YES"  |  Ang=="YES" | Stroke=="YES", "YES, "NO")`

Comment: Try `c("NO", "YES")[(rowSums(df1==="YES")!=0)+1]`

Comment: @BWilliams Thanks! That did it. Except you forgot a " after the "YES


    `CVD <- ifelse (MI=="YES" | Ang=="YES" | Stroke=="YES", "YES","NO")`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowSums` to create the "YES"/"NO" variable

```
 df1$CVD <- c("NO", "YES")[(rowSums(df1=="YES")!=0)+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I interpret it correctly, but I think this should be it:

```
if (any(Mi,Ang,Stroke)) {CVD <- T} else {CVD <- F}
```